Docker image runs in Docker Desktop but hangs over CLI
I have a NLP model that I serve via litserve on Docker.
Dockerfile is
FROM python:3.9
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./src /code/app/src
COPY ./assets/finetuned_BERT_epoch_3.model /code/app/assets/
EXPOSE 8080:8080
WORKDIR /code/app/src
CMD ["python", "server.py"

The docker image downloads a hugging face model and a tokenizer at initialization.
if I run it with
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 huk_nlp:latest

I get stuck. It does not start up:
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1132: FutureWarning: `resume_download` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.

If I start the same image from Docker Desktop, however, it is running perfectly fine:
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
tokenizer_config.json: 100% 48.0/48.0 [00:00<00:00, 13.3kB/s]
vocab.txt: 100% 232k/232k [00:00<00:00, 1.09MB/s]
tokenizer.json: 100% 466k/466k [00:00<00:00, 1.48MB/s]
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1132: FutureWarning: `resume_download` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.
warnings.warn(
config.json: 100% 570/570 [00:00<00:00, 573kB/s]

model.safetensors: 100% 440M/440M [00:26<00:00, 16.5MB/s] 

Setup complete for worker 0.

Truncation was not explicitly activated but `max_length` is provided a specific value, please use `truncation=True` to explicitly truncate examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy to `truncation`.

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py:2699: FutureWarning: The `pad_to_max_length` argument is deprecated and will be removed in a future version, use `padding=True` or `padding='longest'` to pad to the longest sequence in the batch, or use `padding='max_length'` to pad to a max length. In this case, you can give a specific length with `max_length` (e.g. `max_length=45`) or leave max_length to None to pad to the maximal input size of the model (e.g. 512 for Bert).

INFO:     172.17.0.1:36784 - "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

Anyone has an idea why that is?
Thanks

If you send requests to it, does it answer?  If it does answer HTTP requests but isn't printing logs, you could be hitting Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container?  It's possible Docker Desktop is adding something like a -t option to allocate a tty, which would change the output buffering behavior.
